# Firefox conditional comments CSS

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to position a button. I want it to be above the "Gå Videre" button on the page, it works in Safari and Chrome but not IE or FF.

```
#cartUpdate {
    position:absolute;
    width:160px;
    height:30px;
    left:580px;
    bottom:50px;
}
```

And

```
    {capture assign="cartUpdate"}

        <div id="cartUpdate"><!--<input type="submit" class="submit" value="{tn _update}" />-->
        <button type="submit" class="submit" id="oppdatersubmit" name="saveFields" title="Oppdater" value="">&nbsp;</button> </div>
    {/capture}
    {assign var="cartUpdate" value=$cartUpdate|@str_split:10000}
    {php}$GLOBALS['cartUpdate'] = $this->get_template_vars('cartUpdate'); $this->assign_by_ref('GLOBALS', $GLOBALS);{/php}

    {form action="controller=order action=update" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" handle=$form id="cartItems"}

CONTENT


{/form}
```

Can be seen live at www.euroworker.no/order (put something in the basket first (Kjøp and Handlevogn)

EDIT: Just noticed my backend editor has stopped updating the .tpl file.. Might have something to do with it, no updates have been made for hours according to what's on the FTP. Just one thing after another...

Thanks.

Comment: For what do you want to apply the hack?

Comment: Firefox doesn't support conditional comments.  It would be better to ask why your CSS is not working properly in Firefox and post some sample HTML or a link to the page so we can help you fix the problem rather than hack around it.

Comment: what is it that you want to hack? chances are there's no real need for a hack either. could you please post the smallest possible amount of code that will reproduce the error, that renders differently in chrome and firefox. preferably with a jsbin.com link for experimentation.

Comment: You shouldn't make table cells with `position: absolute`; it won't work well.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I changed that td hours ago..

Comment: In before firefox fanboi shitstorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try a separate CSS file:

```
  <!-- IF NOT INTERNET EXPLORER THEN -->
  <![if !IE]>
  <!-- INCLUDE THIS CSS SHEET -->
    <link href="css/ff.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]>
```

Comment: This will also be processed by Opera and WebKit.

Comment: Thanks, I already am using separate sheets for IE and other browsers.

Comment: since you accepted this answer, I think you should explain what's going on here. That code just says: "include the following if the browser is not IE", which means it will include that stylesheet if the browser is, say, Chrome, and you explicitly said you wanted to differentiate between chrome and firefox.

Comment: The original question never stated anything about Chrome did it? It's been a long week so far... it's only Monday

Comment: Ok well I just built it in Firefox, then added @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {.

This fixed my problem, but I accepted this answer as it is a way to differentiate between browsers..

Answer (score 5):

Try to use -moz- prefix for all properties.

Answer (score 0):

as @Neurofluxation conditional comments are best to handle the problems with IE, since you are having it with FF, just use FF CSS as default one and conditions for IE style sheets, you can also tweak your CSS for Firefox by using javascript you can explicitly say if Firefox is my browser use this style sheet, but that is a bad idea since javascript can be disabled and you website is leaved with bad layout.

Comment: Ok, I shall rephrase my questions :) Thanks.

Comment: Agree completey with @c0mrade. I was just answering the question directly. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { selector { attr } }
```